# What is the curved asymptote of $\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{3x-2}}$?

Tags: functions, asymptotics

Please excuse any non-technical language I use...

I'm confused by the process for finding the curved asymptote (as $x$ gets really large) of the graph $y=\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{3x-2}}$.

I first looked at the (naive?) approach of separating the fraction up into two parts:

\begin{align} y &=  \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{3x-2}} \\
&=  \frac{x}{\sqrt{3x-2}} +  \frac{1}{\sqrt{3x-2}} \\
\text{as } x \rightarrow \infty, \quad y &\rightarrow \frac{x}{\sqrt{3x-2}}
\end{align}

Seemed ok, rationale being that the 1/sqrt part goes to zero compared to the ~ sqrt() part.

Then after a bit of searching I came to this video presented here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aWFSNbl2Ho and tried a similar method as presented...

\begin{align}
y &= \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{3x-2}} \\
&= \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{3x-2}} \times \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{3-\frac{2}{x}}} \\ \\
\text{as } x \rightarrow \infty, \quad y &\rightarrow \sqrt{\frac{x}{3}}
\end{align}

Which looks close(ish).

Wolfram Alpha however has different ideas: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D(x%2B1)%2Fsqrt(3x-2)+asymptotes

It gives the relation $x=3y^2-\frac{8}{3}$ which rearranges to a similar curve to my attempt:
$$y=\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{3x-8}$$

Am I on the right track with any of my attempts? I feel like I'm closer with the 2nd attempt but I'm not allowed to disappear both the $1/\sqrt{2}$ and the $2/x$ parts like that.

Comment: What **is** a curved asymptote, to begin with? Is it defined at all? Under what seems to be an intuitive definition, each curve $y(x)$ is a curved asymptote to itself. If you want it different, use $y(x)+{1\over x}$ - why not?

Comment: The answer to this question relies heavily on how "curved asymptote" is defined in your class.

Comment: All three asymptotics are equally valid. However, if forced to pick one, mathematicians would go for the one in the video as it's the easiest to analyse.

Comment: Interesting. I'm a high-school Maths teacher and this question came up so I thought I would explore it with my students. I guess by 'curved asymptote' I was thinking something like $\frac{x^4-x^2}{x^2}$ gets really really close to the curve $y=x^2-1$ as $x$ gets $\pm$ large.

Comment: This is too vague for a definition. Again, each curve gets really really close to itself plus $1\over x$, and also to itself minus $1\over x$, and also to _just itself_. Which of these is an asymptote?

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I made a mistake with my example (which you rightly pointed out was the same curve (mostly)). I meant something like $\frac{x^4-1}{x^2}$ which has an asymptote $y=x^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using equivalents, when $x$ is large $$x+1\sim x \qquad ,  \qquad \sqrt{3x-2}\sim \sqrt{3x}\qquad \implies y \sim \frac{x}{\sqrt{3x}}=\frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Letting $x=\frac 1t$, you also could write $$y=\frac{1+\frac 1t}{\sqrt{\frac 3t  -2}}=\frac 1{\sqrt t}\frac{1+t}{\sqrt{ 3  -2t}}$$ Now, use Taylor expansion around $t=0$ (or the generalized binomial theorem) $$\sqrt{ 3  -2t}=\sqrt{3}-\frac{t}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{t^2}{6 \sqrt{3}}+O\left(t^3\right)$$ $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{ 3  -2t}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{t}{3 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{t^2}{6 \sqrt{3}}+O\left(t^3\right)$$ $$\frac{1+t}{\sqrt{ 3  -2t}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{4 t}{3 \sqrt{3}}+O\left(t^2\right)$$ $$y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{t}}+\frac{4 \sqrt{t}}{3 \sqrt{3}}+O\left(t^{3/2}\right)$$ Now, replace $t$ by $\frac 1x$ to get $$y=\sqrt{\frac x 3}+\frac 4{2\sqrt{3x}}+\cdots$$ which shows the curve asymptote and how it is approached.

**Edit**

Concerning the different approximations, let us consider $$\Delta_1=\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{3x-2}}-\sqrt{\frac x 3}\qquad , \qquad \Delta_2=\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{3x-2}}-\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{3x-8}$$ and use Taylor expansion of the ratio. You should get $$\frac{\Delta_1}{\Delta_2}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{7}{96 x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}\right)$$ that is to say that you are twice better.

Comment: So what I did in the second one was ok. So how does Wolfram Alpha get its answer? Its answer looks so much closer to the curve than my sqrt(x/3).

Comment: You are much better. Compute for $x=1000$; the exact value is $18.2818$; using your formula, $18.2574$; using WA formula $18.2331$; using the term I introduced $18.2818$.

Answer (score 0):

All of the asymptotes you have described are valid according to the definitions below:

---

Similar to what is found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations), we could say that $f(x)\sim g(x)$ means that $f$ and $g$ are *relatively asymptotic*:
$$
f(x)\sim g(x)\implies \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\to1\quad\text{as }x\to\infty
$$
Based on this we could define a class of functions $[f(x)]^{\sim}$ consisting of all functions $g(x)$ being relatively asymptotic to $f$. This will be an equivalence class.

---

Furthermore, we could define the notion of being *strongly asymptotic*, $f(x)\simeq g(x)$, as follows:
$$
f(x)\simeq g(x)\implies |f(x)-g(x)|\to0\quad\text{as }x\to\infty
$$
and the corresponding equivalence class $[f(x)]^{\simeq}$. The examples you gave are all in this latter class. For instance we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{3x-2}}-\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt3}
&=\frac{(x+1)\sqrt3-\sqrt{3x-2}\sqrt x}{\sqrt{3x-2}\sqrt 3}\\
&=\frac{(1+\frac1x)\sqrt3-\sqrt{3-\frac2x}}{\frac1x\sqrt{3x-2}\sqrt 3}
\end{align}
$$
and now since $\sqrt{3-t}>\sqrt3(1-\frac t3)$ for $t>0$ close enough to zero, which can be seen using that the derivative of $\sqrt x$ at $x=3$ is $\frac 1{2\sqrt 3}>\frac13$, we get with $t=\frac2x$ which is close to zero for large $x$ that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{3x-2}}-\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt3}
&<\frac{(1+\frac1x)\sqrt3-\sqrt3(1-\frac2{3x})}{\frac1x\sqrt{3x-2}\sqrt 3}\\
&=\frac{\frac1{3x}}{\frac1x\sqrt{3x-2}}\\
&=\frac1{3\sqrt{3x-2}}
\end{align}
$$
which tends to zero as $x$ tends to infinity.